# Where is the Desktop Slideshow using RSS as the source, for Windows 7 RTM?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, rss, slideshow

I've heard that you can have your desktop background change, based on a directory or location of photo's. Kewl.

[This post](http://www.withinwindows.com/2008/11/03/Windows-7-to-let-users-create-a-desktop-slideshow-from-files-rss-feeds/) says the location can be an RSS feed -> awesome!

A sample RSS feed could be [NASA's Image of the Day](http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss).

So .. how do I do it, in Windows 7 RTM? I can't find the option, anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I based it on the 'Bing.theme' examples, and changed the RssFeed url, from Ivo's answer.

```
[[Theme]
DisplayName=Bing

[Slideshow]
Interval=1800000
Shuffle=1
RssFeed=http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss

[Control Panel\Desktop]
TileWallpaper=0
WallpaperStyle=0
Pattern=

[Control Panel\Cursors]
AppStarting=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_working.ani
Arrow=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_arrow.cur
Crosshair=
Hand=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_link.cur
Help=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_helpsel.cur
IBeam=
No=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_unavail.cur
NWPen=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_pen.cur
SizeAll=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_move.cur
SizeNESW=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_nesw.cur
SizeNS=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_ns.cur
SizeNWSE=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_nwse.cur
SizeWE=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_ew.cur
UpArrow=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_up.cur
Wait=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_busy.ani
DefaultValue=Windows Aero
Link=

[VisualStyles]
Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles
ColorStyle=NormalColor
Size=NormalSize
ColorizationColor=0X6B74B8FC
Transparency=1

[MasterThemeSelector]
MTSM=DABJDKT
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a quick HowTo](http://on10.net/blogs/sarahintampa/Get-a-Live-Updating-Bing-Wallpaper-Windows-7-Theme/), the quick and dirty way to get the NASA daily image as your background. For more resources check [IStartedSomething](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090126/rss-powered-windows-7-desktop-slideshows/) and [MakeUseOfUs](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-a-bing-wallpaper-desktop-slideshow-in-windows-7/) and for some useful troubleshooting tips if you can't get it to work.

[image]

1. Copy this text into Notepad:

   ```
   [Theme] 
   DisplayName=NASA 

   [Slideshow] 
   Interval=1800000 
   Shuffle=1 
   RssFeed=http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss

   [Control Panel\Desktop] 
   TileWallpaper=0 
   WallpaperStyle=0 
   Pattern=

   [Control Panel\Cursors] 
   AppStarting=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_working.ani 
   Arrow=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_arrow.cur 
   Crosshair= 
   Hand=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_link.cur 
   Help=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_helpsel.cur 
   IBeam= 
   No=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_unavail.cur 
   NWPen=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_pen.cur 
   SizeAll=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_move.cur 
   SizeNESW=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_nesw.cur 
   SizeNS=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_ns.cur 
   SizeNWSE=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_nwse.cur 
   SizeWE=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_ew.cur 
   UpArrow=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_up.cur 
   Wait=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_busy.ani 
   DefaultValue=Windows Aero 
   Link=

   [VisualStyles] 
   Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles 
   ColorStyle=NormalColor 
   Size=NormalSize 
   ColorizationColor=0X6B74B8FC 
   Transparency=1

   [MasterThemeSelector] 
   MTSM=DABJDKT
   ```
2. Save the file as “NASA.theme”
3. Activate the theme. Double-click on the NASA.theme file to launch it. In the Subscribe to RSS Feed? prompt, click Download Attachments.

After following the three above steps, you’ll now see the NASA theme appear on your screen. It will also be stored in the “My Themes” section of your personalization options.

Edit: I changed it to NASA, but I'm not sure if the RSS feed works like this, alternatively you could load up a feedburner link.

Comment: +1 Bing feed isn't working, but by changing the feed to nasa, it works like a charm. Also the formatting has to be perfect. Adjust it so it's the same as on th "howto-blogpost"

Comment: first tag has double [[, should be [

Comment: Doesn't work :( I get the error "This theme can't be applied to the desktop. Try clicking a different theme.". This was after i double-clicked on the new file i made (and renamed to NASA.theme). ??? BTW, i'm on Win7 RTM (MSDN edition).

Comment: Lol then the [[ seems intentional